# Parameter Prescription: 1 Tablix and 3 Fields. Why Won't They Sync?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

Imagine a world where there are 2 Datasets:

- "Lookup," for parameter lookup, and
- "Main," for the report body's Tablix.

Lookup has just 3 fields:

- "FromDate,"
- "ToDate," and
- "DateRange,"

where a row entry such as "04/01/2015" (date), "03/31/2016" (date), and "04/01/2015 - 03/31/2016" (string) may appear.

3 parameters (bound to Lookup; Value and Label fields set accordingly) appear on the report, consistent with the above 3 fields:

- "FromDate,"
- "ToDate," and
- "DateRange."

The user selects a DateRange, and that is supposed to fill in the other two parameters, the latter marked as (invisible) "Internal."  Those FromDate and ToDate report parameters match the names of Main's parameters, which are supposed to pull the matching rows from Main and display them on the report.

Unless I hard-code some from/to in the Default/Specify Values of the FromDate and ToDate report parameters, depending on what I try, I get one of a series of odd errors, such as:

- "Parameter validation failed.  It is not possible to provide valid values for all parameters. (rsParameterError)"

My goal is the intended functionality as well as a default of the most-recent date range populating on start-up the report parameters.

Comment: Make sure DateRange is at the top of the parameter list because [parameter order is important when you have cascading parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255258.aspx)

Comment: What is the purpose of this "DateRange" parameter? Can't you just filter the Main dataset results using the "FromDate" and "ToDate"? If the Main dataset has a "DateRange" column, consider parsing it into the two separate dates.

Comment: @Stubaker hit the nail on the head:  Parameter order.  Thanks!

Comment: @StevenWhite: While DateRange could have been a simple, on-the-fly concatenation, it was already alongside FromDate and ToDate, so, the logic was to give the user solely the DateRange dropdown and let that drive the FromDate and ToDate to be used in the main query.  Thanks!